# What is the default password of the UEC image?

Tags: openstack, uec

I'm running some instances using Ubuntu image 10.04 on Openstack. Here is the link:

https://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04/release/

I can use the private key to ssh to these instances, it's ok. But I don't know the default password to VNC to these instance. So what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Tim. There is no password for 'root' or 'ubuntu' user in UEC image. So I just use the private key and ssh to UEC instance, then create a new user/password. After that I can login in VNC console to that instance.

Answer (score 2):

All the passwords have been disabled on UEC images.  For VNC, you will probably need to explicitly set one using `vncpasswd`.